# Powershell - Set -server flag globally (AD cmdlets)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to set the `-server` flag globally for a whole script using the Active Directory cmdlets.

My issue is that I am running a script from a different domain, and have a few domains I need to execute these commands on, from a single management domain.

Example:

```
Get-ADUser 'john' -server domain1.acme.com
```

However I'd like to just run:

```
Get-ADUser 'john'
```

from domain2, without having to specify a -server flag every time I use an AD cmdlet.

Currently, I am simply declaring a `$server` variable and inserting it into every command, e.g. `Get-ADUser 'john' -server $server`

But this is rather messy and I feel like there must be a better way. My research has yielded nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$PSDefaultParameterValues` for this,The below example for adding server parameter default value for get-aduser:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add('Get-ADUser:server', 'domain1.acme.com')
```

after `psdefaultparametervalue` addition you can use the commandlet like this :

```
Get-ADUser 'john'
```

PSDefaultParameterValues supports wildcard as well

`$PSDefaultParameterValues.Add('Get-AD*:server', 'localhost')`

For reference:
https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/12/03/use-powershell-default-parameter-values-to-simplify-scripts/

PS: This feature will work only from PowerShell V3 onwards

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect. I've used `*-AD*:server` which gets most get/set for AD cmdlets. Of course each script is tested so there might be a few like Get-GPO and so on that get missed (and fixed), however realistically I might try `*:server` and just hope/assume all of my cmdlets that have a -server flag still work.